# C++ - Objects in Vector Unable to be Modified

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to make a class that stores a vector of `Chest`s where `Chest` is a custom class I've made. Here is the relevant portion of `ItemManager.h`:

```
class ItemManager
{
public:
    ...
    void GenerateItems(sf::Vector2u currentPos);
    void CheckCollisions(Collider& collider);
    ...

private:
    std::vector<Chest> chests;
};
```

And then here is (the relevant portions of) `ItemManager.cpp`:

```
void ItemManager::GenerateItems(sf::Vector2u currentPos)
{
    if (rand() % 50 == 0)
        chests.push_back(Chest(sf::Vector2f(16 * currentPos.x + 1, 16 * currentPos.y - 4 - 2)));
}

void ItemManager::CheckCollisions(Collider & collider)
{
    for (Chest chest : chests)
        if (collider.CheckCollision(chest.getCollider(), 1.0f))
            chest.OnInteract();
}
```

The issue I am now having is that even when `chest.OnInteract()` is being called in `CheckCollisions()`, nothing is happening to the chest. However this is not an issue with the method because when I call `chest.OnInteract()` in the method `GenerateItems()`, it applies what is to be expected to the chest. My belief is that, because I am creating a local variable in another method to add the the `vector`, the object being added goes out of scope and I can no longer reference it. However it was my belief that adding to a `vector` creates a copy and so this should not be an issue. Any help is appreciated.
**Edit**
Here is my `OnInteract()` method:

```
void Chest::OnInteract()
{
    open = true;
    chest.setSize(sf::Vector2f(14, 16));
    chest.move(sf::Vector2f(0, -2));
    chest.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(14, 0, 14, 16));
}
```

where `open` and `chest` are member variables of `Chest`.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop:

```
for (Chest chest : chests) { ... }
```

will make a temporary copy of `Chest` objects, so the `OnInteract()` method will be called on that temporary object. What you want instead is a reference to the object, like so:

```
for (Chest &chest : chests) { ... }
```

so that changes (presumibly happening in the `OnInteract()` method) are applied to the objects inside your `chests` container and not a temporary copy of them.

Comment: Okay, I figured it would be something along those lines. However, I just tried what you said and it didn't seem to make any difference: Do I need to also edit how I reference chest inside the loop?

Comment: No, the rest is ok. How your `OnInteract()` method looks like?

Comment: Also, are you sure the condition of the `if` statement will ever return `true`? It might be your program never executes the `OnInteract()` method because the `if` is never taken.

Comment: I published the `OnInteract()` method but I'm fairly certain that's not the issue as it works in other contexts. Also I have verified that the `if` statement is called via debug outputs.

Comment: Next guess is that you are colling the `CheckCollisions` method on a temporary (copy) object of `ItemManager` as well. To make sure you are not 'accidentally' creating copies of objects you don't want to be copied you can add a private copy constructor to the class definition and the compiler will spot all places where you are making temporary copies.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `chest.OnInteract()`, you actually copy your `Chest` object:

```
//       ,--- Chest is a local variable, not a reference.
//       v    It is constructing with the value of each chest in chests.
for (Chest chest : chests)
    if (collider.CheckCollision(chest.getCollider(), 1.0f))
        chest.OnInteract();
```

You can solve your problem simply by creating a reference instead of an object:

```
for (auto&& chest : chests)
    if (collider.CheckCollision(chest.getCollider(), 1.0f))
        chest.OnInteract();
```

`auto&&` simply means that you want a reference no matter the type, value category or cv qualifiers. It is the preferred way to create a variable in a range based for loop.

Comment: Sadly I still have the same issue, however I will also look through my code and see if I made the same error anywhere else that could be fixed.